# Routing domain hosted in third-party to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I am trying to direct a URL request to an AWS S3 bucket.
So far I have done the following:

1. Create a bucket with the name app-name.app (domain is .app)
2. Make the bucket public and set property as a static website.
3. Website works fine when directly accessed through the S3 ARN.

Now I need to direct my (Godaddy) hosted domain name to this S3 bucket.
These are the steps I've taken:

1. Create a hosted zone in Route 53
2. Create record sets for A, NS and SOA types.
   This is how it looks like:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
3. After that I set the same NS server names in to Godaddy domain. I then also received an email from Godaddy stating that the nameservers have been changed.

However, I am not able to access the site through the domain name. It times out. 
Appreciate some help figuring out what step I am missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1-Make sure your DNS changed correctly, by ping and trace.

2-Use DNS tools like mxtoolbox to check the records.

3-Add CNAME record with your S3 website public URL(It's different as S3 general URL), for example, add www.

Comment: Thanks Reza but didn't work. I ended up directly forwarding to the S3 end-point from Godaddy domain forwarding.

Comment: It should be work; I'm sure you missed some steps or parts.